# Foreground Service closes after a while

Tags: java, android, foreground, foreground-service

I am working on a Location service which retrieves the location of a user every 5 minutes or if it detects movement. To continuously fetch data in the background, I am using foreground service.

After several hours the foreground services stop working and the notification disappears. Can't use JobScheduler because system kill in doze mode (see documentation [Optimize apps](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby#restrictions))

Service:

```
<service
        android:name="com.spotbros.service.ForegroundService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:process=":location" >
    </service>
```

Logs in the logcat:

```
2020-06-30 11:20:02.278 26865-26865/com.spotbros.defense D/ForegroundService$2: onLocationResult - LocationManager: onLocationResult latitude: 40.3968481 longitude: -3.6219455
```

Build the notification:

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_CHANNEL_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS);
        notificationIntent.putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_APP_PACKAGE, this.getPackageName());
        notificationIntent.putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_CHANNEL_ID, "serviceNotificationChannelId");
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
                0, notificationIntent, 0);
        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle(appName)
                .setContentText(getString(R.string.sending_location))
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo_notif_large)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MIN)
                .build();
        startForeground(1, notification);
```

Call AlarmManager:

```
if (!com.spotbros.desktop.comms.protocol.WebServerTypesDefinition.LOCATION_SERVICE_MODE_DISABLED.equals(event.getLocationServiceMode()) /*&&
locationManager.permissionGranted*/) {
            Logger.d("Location service is not disabled: " + event.getLocationServiceMode());
            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, ForegroundService.class);
            serviceIntent.setAction(ForegroundService.START_FOREGROUND_SERVICE);
            serviceIntent.putExtra(ForegroundService.CHANNEL_ID_STRING, IdManager.getAsUniqueAndPersistentAsPossibleId(credentials.email));
            final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, serviceIntent, 0);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + ForegroundService.MIN_TIME,pendingIntent);
            ContextCompat.startForegroundService(context, serviceIntent);
        }
```

Comment: Are you getting location at high_accuracy ?

Comment: Sure,                 mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);